# Reducing Foundation's row spacing

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am using Found 4.04. I have a text box inside a form and I am trying to place some text right beneath the text box. However, there is a bit more space than I would like and I want to cut it down. I tried tweaking the margin, padding, etc. using Firebug and nothing has worked.

Is there a way to reduce the *vertical space* between the text boxes and their corresponding placement text? i.e., "Small text goes here" will move up closer to the text box.

Here is the JSFiddle link (you will have to shrink the code panel so you can see the boxes side by side): http://jsfiddle.net/R95JL/

```
 <html>
 <head><meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport">
 <link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/4.0.4/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>

 <body>
 <h4> Test form </h4>
 <br> <br>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="" method="post">
            <div class="large-3 columns"> Text </div>
            <div class="large-2 columns"><input type="number" value="" required="" name="f2" id="myid1"></div>
            <div class="large-2 large-offset-1 columns end"><input type="number" value="" required="" name="f3" id="myid2"></div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="large-offset-3 large-2 columns"><small> Small text goes here </small> </div>
        <div class="large-2 large-offset-1 columns end"><small> Small text goes here </small> </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is unlikely a simple hack :

```
#myid2 {
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/R95JL/10/)

Also note that your form is `float`'ed....so you'll have to use

`.clr{
    clear:both;
}`

and unlike the other answers, using `input {margin:0px !important;}` is not recommended as this will affect all the `input` fields and the form layout too... [see what i mean](http://jsfiddle.net/R95JL/11/)!!

Comment: Thanks. I definitely don't want to override the input element across the entire site so your solution works much better in that regard. I wanted to move both the text up so I applied the same style for both the IDs.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the margin from the input boxes in your CSS.

```
 input { margin:0px !important;  }
```

Answer (score 1):

your input is having default margin. Use this rule in css:

```
input {margin:0px !important;}
```